# Best way to check for type in Angular - instanceof is the best way here?

Tags: angular, typescript, types

In the model

```
import { Type1, Type2 } from '.';
export type TypeComp = Type1 | Type2;
```

The `selectedData$` observable is used in the `some.component.ts` and `{{selectedData$ | async}}` is used in its template.
What's the best way to check (or even to display) (ideally in the template, but per what I see there is no such way) if `{{selectedData$ | async}}` has `Type1` or `Type2`.

UPD: To clarify, I'd like to **use** and display `{{(selectedData$ | async).propAFromType1}}` or another properties from Type1 or Type2, but without exceptions that will appear because these properties are the properties **exactly** of one Type **Type1** or `Type2`, but not both (not TypeComp properties).

I don't want to put separate properties in both Type1 and Type2.

Comment: Why do you want to check the type in template? maybe [`enable template type check`](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck) Your question is a bit unclear, could you elaborate on the problem you are facing, with minimal reproducible code?

Comment: Naren Murali, I added more details. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value will be either in `type1` or `type2` please do a simple `or` check and render in the html like so.

> Note: The `$any` is to get rid of the type check in HTML, since you are 100% certain that there will be only two properties, I am using this `$any` type to override the typescript error!

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
  if you want the tag
    <h1 *ngIf="$any(name$ | async) as test" [innerHTML]="test && (test.title || test.title2)">
    </h1>
  if you do not want the tag<br/><br/>
    <h1 *ngIf="$any(name$ | async) as test" [outerHTML]="test && (test.title || test.title2)">
    </h1>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name$: Observable<{ title: string } | { title2: string }> = of({
    title: 'Angular',
  });
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-az6ewr)

---

## References

1. [Template Type Checking](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck)